# Modify .htaccess to remove content after 2nd slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have one website running in that we need to modify .htaccess. There has been the error reported by Google that URL is being appended by one more PHP file.

Such as `http://www.example.com/test-file.php/test1-file.php`

We need to either remove test1-file.php or redirect to the 404.php page using `.htaccess`

My .htaccess looks like below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404.php

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php    
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}${REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

# remove content after 2nd slash
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)/.*$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```